# @OneToOne mappedBy insertion error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, model-view-controller

I have two entity classes User and Record related to user and record table, where the record table has a column for user_id. But the user table doesnot need to have a record_id, so that mappedBy is used. My entity class mapping is as follows:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@Entity
public class Record{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

.....getters and setters

}

@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
    private Record record;

....getters and setters
}
```

While an insert method, the functionality is like that both the tabes will be filled. The user table and record table is filled while insert method execution, except the user_id column in record table.
What may be the issue. Any help apprciated.

Comment: Post the code you save the entities

Comment: Nothing is done there in addition, since that was the code that was working fine with groovy domain classes. Then that groovy domain where converted to java entity. After the convertion only the method is not working..So this will be the case of mapping issue.

Comment: The mapping seems ok, but as @aviad asked you have to post how you save the entities; otherwise, difficult to help you.